# where does systemd store service STATE of enabled and disabled

Tags: systemd

```
systemctl list-unit-files
```

shows all systemd services and their corresponding STATE for if they are **enabled** or **disabled**, or static.

All I know is either `systemctl enable|disable <service>`, and the above command to know what its state is.

Does systemd store this information in some plain text file, that I can go `vi` to see and manually change a service state between enabled and disabled?  For example when a RHEL install is under a virtual file system, which is used to diskless boot cluster nodes.

Comment: Note, `systemctl` can take a `--root=` option to specify a different directory to operate on. I don't know how effective it is for the commands you might want to use.

Answer (score 1):

Enabling and disabling services adds and removes symlinks in target directory specified by `WantedBy` in the install block respectively.

Say the unit file declared `WantedBy=multi-user.target`. When you enable that service `/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/ntpd.service`, for example, points to  `/usr/lib/systemd/system/ntpd.service` and therefore ntpd starts up when multi-user.target is reached.

Comment: is it correct to say : systemd service listing as a whole is global, but whether an individual service is enabled or disabled is dependent on runlevel and default.target?

Comment: Yes. I updated the answer to explain it better.

Comment: so then i would manually have to scour the folder contents of runlevels 1..5 (the systemd syntax) up to whatever *default-target* is set to, to know what services are enabled?  And if a symlink is not there then if the service file does exist it is disabled?

Comment: Yes. That method works. Or you can just test to see what the `WantedBy` is set to and see if that service file exists in that target rather then sifting through the directory.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're trying to accomplish but the proper way to check whether a service is enabled or not is via [`systemctl is-enabled service_name`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemctl.html) (check the table in the man page for a list of possible status values):

```
systemctl is-enabled upower
```

```
disabled
```

---

Also, note that some services might run/load without ever being enabled, like the above-mentioned `upower`:

```
systemctl status upower    
● upower.service - Daemon for power management
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/upower.service; disabled; preset: disabled)
     Active: active (running) ......
     ...............................
     CGroup: /system.slice/upower.service
             └─1097 /usr/lib/upowerd
```